# Can't mount any partition due to "/usb: Adding read ACL for uid 1000 to /media/evil' failed: Operation not supported" error

Tags: usb, mount

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 and now I can't mount any partition. I get the same error with all drives:

```
/usb: Adding read ACL for uid 1000 to /media/evil' failed: Operation not supported
```

Both of my USB drives are FAT32, one is a USB stick, the other is a GOPRO cam and both were working fine in 12.04.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case after upgraded to UBUNTU 12.10 my username in /media didn't exist, so I created it and problem SOLVED!

Comment: Same for me. I just executed `chown user:user /media/user' afterwards.

Answer (score 9):

It is bad advice to use permission `777` on anything. Any user on the system gets read/write access to your files.

```
sudo mkdir /media/${USER}
sudo chown ${USER}.${USER} /media/${USER}
chmod 750 /media/${USER}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be a ":" instead of a "." between the first and second mentioning of the username? As in "sudo chown Username:Username /media/Username".

Comment: When talking about another answer, please use a comment on it. Due to changes in voting, the post you are referring to is no longer above your post.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try to mount those drives manually, using terminal:

```
mount -t devicefilesystem /dev/something /media/something
```

for example `mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /media/windows` but before doing this, you have to create directory **windows** (or other, it's up to you) in **/media** like this `mkdir /media/windows`.
This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty method:
I have same problem and it seemed I solved by changing user owner and group owner of the directory: `/media/<your username>`

In command line type

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/<your username>
sudo chmod 777 /media/<your username>
sudo chown <username> /media/<your username>
```

Pluck out usb device put it back in and it should start working

Comment: 777 is bad advise